# Select a point on a map and display it on an input

Tags: javascript, php, html, web, maps

I would like to know if there's a way to show a map on a form, select a point on that map and display the address in an input like a textbox and viceversa (to write an address in that textbox and show a point on the map), and save that address in a variable.

It would be very useful something like an `<input type="map">` with its own properties but I don't know if that exists.

Comment: You can do this by `Google Map`

Comment: I tried with the Google Maps api but didn't quite understand how it works...

Comment: Have you tried reading through the Google Maps API documentation?

Comment: I'm gonna do that right now, but if someone has another solution, you know, just in case, that would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found a solution, in Google Maps API there's an example that displays a map with a search box: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox?hl=es, I created a function that obtains the value of the search box and displays it into an input of type text:

```
function getAddress(){
var address = document.getElementById('pac-input').value;
document.getElementById('address').value = address;
}
```

Where "pac-input" is the id of the search box and "address" is the id of the input that I created.